# Perf Table is not accessible in Azure Log Analytics for my IOT Edge Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, perf, azure-log-analytics

I have enabled log Analytics via the collector module for all my IOTedge Devices. I am successfully able to scrape data from my devices which are available in Insights Metric.

Besides the above, I have also enabled Performance Counter but I am unable to see any data inside Perf Table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the Upload Target: AzureMonitor or IoT Hub ?

Comment: The Upload Target is the default option.